# SSRS Recursive Sum

Tags: sql, visual-studio, recursion, reporting-services

I have created a tablet report in vs2017 [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzMVf.png). Each balanceindicator has a parent key. For my "Sum at the end of last year" field i have configure a recursive sum by parentKey for BalanceIndicatorKey group. At this point all is good and works perfectly. Now i have added a column group by organizationKey. What i need is to get the recursive sum for each organization considering the Organization and balance indicator [My report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3aGh.png)

Here is the stored procedure that i use for my report

```
LTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFactBalance] 

@organizationKey int,
@year int,
@month int

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

;with cte_Orgs
 as
 (
    select OrganizationKey,
           [Description]
    from DimOrganization o
    where o.OrganizationKey = @organizationKey
    union all
    select o.OrganizationKey,
           o.[Description]
    from cte_Orgs join
         DimOrganization o on o.ParentKey = cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey
 ),
 cte_start as (
    select
        Sum(fa.SumReg) SumReg,
        fa.BalanceIndicatorKey,
        cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey,
        cte_Orgs.Description
    from FactBalance fa join
         cte_Orgs on cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey = fa.OrganizationKey
    where fa.OrganizationKey = cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey
    and [Year] = @year-1 and [Month] = 12
    group by
    fa.BalanceIndicatorKey,
    cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey,
    cte_Orgs.Description
    ),

  cte_curr as (

        select
        Sum(fa.SumReg) SumReg,
        fa.BalanceIndicatorKey,
        cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey,
        cte_Orgs.Description
    from FactBalance fa join 
         cte_Orgs on cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey = fa.OrganizationKey
    where [Year] = @year and [Month] = @month
    group by
    fa.BalanceIndicatorKey,
    cte_Orgs.OrganizationKey,
    cte_Orgs.Description
    ),
   cte_res as (

    select
        ISNULL(cte_curr.BalanceIndicatorKey, cte_start.BalanceIndicatorKey) BalanceIndicatorKey,
        ISNULL(cte_start.OrganizationKey, cte_curr.OrganizationKey) OrganizationKey,
        ISNULL(cte_start.Description, cte_curr.Description) [OrgName],
        cte_start.SumReg SumRegStart,
        cte_curr.SumReg SumReg
    from cte_curr full join cte_start on cte_curr.BalanceIndicatorKey = cte_start.BalanceIndicatorKey
                        and cte_curr.OrganizationKey = cte_start.OrganizationKey)

select
    cte_res.OrganizationKey,
    cte_res.OrgName, 
    bi.BalanceIndicatorKey,
    bi.Description [Description],
    bi.Code,
    bi.ParentKey,
    cte_res.SumRegStart,
    cte_res.SumReg,
    isnull(bi.Level, 0) [Level]
from DimBalanceIndicator bi
full join cte_res on cte_res.BalanceIndicatorKey = bi.BalanceIndicatorKey 
END
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Can you give us a sample query? This shouldn't be very hard if you're just SELECTing [BalanceIndicator], [Organization], and [Amount]. The filed would just be =Sum([Amount]) and the report would handle the summing by group for you.

Comment: Hi Russell. I have added to my question my stored procedur

Comment: Okay, and what are your formulas in the three report columns?

Comment: Thank you Russell for your interest. I have resolved my problem using flattened table. I will try later to put my solution